# scope of \def within a beamer document

Tags: beamer, macros, scoping

The following MWE displays the problem.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    \def\test{hello}
    \test % prints hello
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
    \test % should print hello, but doesn't
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
    \def\test{something new}
    \test % prints something new 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 4}
    \test % should print something new 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am using `\def` simply because it came as part of an answer I found elsewhere on this site. It seems that the macro `\test` is only defined within the scope of the environment (in this case `frame` so perhaps the problem isn't beamer dependent). How can I have the command `\test` defined globally (from this point on)?

Comment: Put `\def\test{hello}` in the preamble. It is safe to use `\newcommand` though.

Comment: \gdef isn't good enough for you?

Comment: `\gdef` was unknown to me and now that it is known it does the trick! Many thanks.

Comment: @HarishKumar Maybe my MWE was too minimal. I added an extra frame to show how I want to use the command.

Comment: @Geoff Simply put it outside the frame.

Comment: @HarishKumar Perhaps, but I have all these `\def`s embedded within a macro. Sometimes I need to make one change and keep all the rest the same. `\gdef` does indeed work.

Comment: This is unrelated to beamer, every latex environment acts as a local scope for definitions.

Comment: @David I had a feeling that was the case.